# Puppeteer: setContent from element with embedded pdf in iframe not loading

Tags: iframe, puppeteer

**Background**: I am successfully using puppeteer to visit an internal site, select an element on the page and convert that element to a PDF. This has been working for a while and most of the code is below. However, I received the requirement to embed a PDF within this element, and this PDF is reachable through that same internal site (e.g. /resources/path/to/pdf). I own this site, so I chose to use an `iframe` to embed this pdf within the element and everything works on the screen when I visit the site.

**Problem**: In puppeter, I am using the target elements `outerHTML` in `page.setContent` to to create a PDF representation of the element. Now that the iframe is a child, puppeteer has a timeout when I have `networkidle0` or `networkidle2` in `page.goto`. If I remove those flags, and even add safe guards to wait for the `iframe`, the PDF has a big gray rectangle where the pdf should be. I realized that using `const html = await element.evaluate((el) => el.outerHTML);` does not grab the `iframe` html, but many attempts at refactoring have not been successful.

I got this to work by taking a pdf of the entire page and removing `setContent`, and if that is the the only way to get this to work, I can work with it.

Thanks

```js
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: false,
          args: [
              "--disable-gpu",
              "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
              "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
              "--no-sandbox",
          ],
      });

 const page = await browser.newPage();

/// timeout here with networkidle
 await page.goto(`path-to-page`, {                                                                                                                           
    waitUntil: ["domcontentloaded", "networkidle0"],                                                                                                        
 });       

 await page.waitForNetworkIdle();
 await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
 const element = await page.waitForSelector(".myform");

// iframe children not available
 const html = await element.evaluate((el) => el.outerHTML);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 await page.setContent(html);                  

 const pdf = await page.pdf({                                                                                                                                    
    format: "a4",                                                                                                                                               
    printBackground: true,                                                                                                                                  
 });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  
await browser.close();
```

Comment: `await page.waitForNetworkIdle();` seems unnecessary. `goto` already does that. Why not capture a pdf of the page rather than using the extra `outerHTML` step? If that doesn't work, please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, that network idle is unnecessary, but I wanted to give the code as is. I did not want to PDF the entire page because the PDF element is only a part of the page. If I print the page, it includes the navbar, buttons etc, so I would have to add an additional stylesheet I did not plan for. Printing the entire page does show the iframe and I get the expected PDF. Using the code above with `setContent` does not work.

Comment: If you want just that frame, why not navigate to the frame on its own? I guess I'm not clear on what you want to capture and what you don't. If you need some elements from the parent document but not others, you could manually delete any elements you don't want, then PDF snapshot the partially-stripped outer page along with the iframe.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The element I want is a form on the page. Within this form are inputs, selects etc. Also within this form is an iframe to an embedded pdf that is basically like a terms of service. I would like to create a pdf of this form while also showing the terms within that iframe. The iframe src links to a pdf file, similar to what the object or embed tag would do (I tried those tags without luck). The selector I am using is the form element

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. You're using the `outerHTML` trick to effectively strip out all content on the page except the form, which should ideally keep showing the PDF in it inside the iframe. It's just that (presumably) the PDF doesn't load in time when you do this, hence the gray box. Maybe try moving your `waitForNetworkIdle()` call down after the `setContent` call? This way, the PDF will be loaded by the time the `.pdf()` call happens. If this doesn't work, I can help if you can provide a sample HTML/PDF combo so I have something to work with.

Comment: Certainly, and thank you! I did add the same `waitUntil` options in the `setContent` and got the timeout as well, but I will move the ` `waitForNetworkIdle()`. If that does not work I will provide a sample.  I am signing off for the day, but will update you in the next few days.

Comment: Hi K J, thanks for replying. The app is a few years old so it was probably never removed. Yes it is chromium plated. I inspected the element contents after  `await page.waitForSelector(".myform")` and the iframe has an embed tag in it, and then the iframe is empty when I inspect the html from  `await element.evaluate((el) => el.outerHTML)`. Based on your comment, seems like it won't render as coded, so I either need to figure out how to  insert a screenshot or just add a special page stylesheet that styles the entire page for printing.

Comment: if I have not misunderstood the issue, you need to use `page.frames()` to get access to the iframe's DOM. Iframe's content is not part of the parent page DOM.